# How to have a continuous calculation in google spreadsheets=

Tags: google-sheets

So, I want to continuously divide something. I have a number, and I want to divide it into a new number, and then divide that new number, and so on. How do I make a google spreadsheet do this?

Comment: If you have to divide by the same number all the time simply go with power i.e. 666/3^6.

If you also need all steps use this formula =ARRAYFORMULA(42/2^(SEQUENCE(5,1,1,1)))  
where 42 is initial number, 2 is divisor, 5 is number of times you want to divide.


If you need something else - add more details.

Comment: That's everything I needed @OlegS, thank you very much! If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to divide by the same number all the time simply go with power i.e. `666/3^6`

If you also need all steps of calculation use this formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(42/2^(SEQUENCE(5,1,1,1)))
```

where 42 is initial number, 2 is divisor, 5 is number of times you want to divide.

Answer (score 0):

You can **cascade** the calculations. In **A1** enter the initial amount.  In **B1** enter the divisor.  In **A2** enter:

```
=A1/$B$1
```

Copy this formula downward.

[image]

In this method each value is based on the value above it.